# Trying to log in on parse server gives "internal server error"

Tags: xcode, mongodb, heroku, parse-server, internal-server-error

My iOS app has suddenly started giving this error message when logging in or creating a new user in the app:

> [Error]: {"code":1,"message":"Internal server error."} (Code: 1, Version: 1.15.4)

Here is the pickle. The app works fine on an earlier version (version 4.4.0) that I have on my iPad. Here I can log in and create a user, and I can add items and delete items while in sync with the server. In the new version of the app (4.4.1) nothing has changed with regards to the code on my login page. I can still fetch data from the server in the app as well, but logging in and creating a user gives the internal server error.

I got my server on Heroku and the database on MongoDB. The database is available and running. However, the server Heroku got several failed throughputs (5xx code) during a day. This says to me that something is going on with the server side of things.

Does anyone know where to turn to next? I can't seem to get my head around where the issue is rising from. I have already sent a mail to Heroku, so I'll make an update when I receive an answer.

But basically, I need help to know what would be my next step to figure out what is causing the error?

Comment: Run `git bisect` to find the commit that introduced this behaviour and work from there: http://webchick.net/node/99

Comment: Found out my database was out of space, so just deleted some documents and it was back on track.